# Dealing with microseconds

Tags: python, datetime

I have written this code where I want that code  to run exactly at the minute. However, each iteration take few milliseconds and this causes a small delay in my program. Is there a way to where I can subtract these milliseconds just like the way I have subtracted seconds.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
import time

while True:
    now = dt.datetime.now()
    current_time = now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    seconds = int(current_time[-2:])
    sleep_sec = 60 - seconds
    time.sleep(sleep_sec)
    print(dt.datetime.now())
```

This is the output:

[image: OUTPUT IMAGE]

As you can see from the output that with each iteration few milliseconds are added to the time. What I want is to print the exact minute where milliseconds is also zero.

Comment: You basically can't since you're not the only process using the computer

Comment: @MadPhysicist Can I subtract those milliseconds too just like I subtracted the seconds??

Comment: No, because your control over when the sleep ends is not of sufficient resolution. The clock has plenty of resolution, but you can't guarantee a time slot for your process unless you change its nice number to coming something ridiculous, at which point you pretty much freeze the system.

Answer (score 1):

using time.time() instead of time.sleep()

```
import time
import datetime as dt
start_time = time.time()

while True:
    if time.time() - start_time > 60:
        # if 60 seconds pass do something
        print(dt.datetime.now())
        start_time = time.time()
        print("60 seconds passed")
```

output:

```
2021-12-24 12:48:30.542806
60 seconds passed
2021-12-24 12:49:30.543792
60 seconds passed
2021-12-24 12:50:30.544508
60 seconds passed
2021-12-24 12:51:30.544826
60 seconds passed
2021-12-24 12:52:30.545028
60 seconds passed
2021-12-24 12:53:30.545661
60 seconds passed
2021-12-24 12:54:30.546452
60 seconds passed
```

there's still offset, but it's less significant than in your output

Answer (score 0):

time.sleep accepts float if you want to sleep for fractions of seconds. That being said I would not expect python to be able to do exact milisecond precision (there is just way too much happening in your system usually for this level of precision).

Answer (score 0):

With threading the code is fast and executes exactly at the start of the minute.

```
def create_candle():
    candle_timeframe = 60 # seconds
    current_sec = dt.datetime.now().second
    sleep_sec = candle_timeframe - current_sec
    print(dt.datetime.now())
    threading.Timer(sleep_sec, create_candle).start()

candle_timeframe = 60 # seconds
current_sec = dt.datetime.now().second
sleep_sec = candle_timeframe - current_sec
threading.Timer(sleep_sec, create_candle).start()
```